# How to set a priority for a reminder - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit

While creating a reminder, I can set alarm for reminder. But I am not able to find any property or method to set priority using objective-c.

```
EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
reminder.title = @"Title";
reminder.calendar = self.calendar;
reminder.dueDateComponents = [self dateComponentsForDefaultDueDate];

EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate: reminderdate]; 
[reminder addAlarm:alarm];
```

Comment: What reminder? Update your question with some relevant code for context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EKReminder` has a priority property.

```
   reminder.priority = 1;
```

It's there, but undocumented, since (it was added in iOS 7, but) the  [EKReminder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/) documentation hasn't been updated since iOS 6.